# MySQL composite indexes and operator BETWEEN

Tags: sql, mysql, composite, indexing, between

I have a question about this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM runs 
 WHERE (NOW() BETWEEN began_at 
                  AND finished_at)
```

Do you think it makes sense to create composite index for began_at and finished_at columns?
Or it makes sense to create index only for began_at?

Comment: put an index on the 'now()' field xD

Comment: @Joe: NOW() isn't a field. It's a database function, and it can't get an index.

Comment: @thaold - LHS comparison is not constant...

Comment: @ajreal: are you saying MySQL *will* use an index if you put an integer there instead?

Comment: @thaold - answer by @Joe Hopfgartner has pointed that out, LHS should be using a constant, instead of NOW()

Comment: @Joe: I get jokes. And emoticons. :)

Comment: @ajreal The result of `NOW()` will not change per row, so MySQL will execute it only once when compiling the query. Thus, it will still effectively be constant. Is that what you're referring to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your style is very uncommon.

Most people would probably write `WHERE began_at < NOW() AND finished_at > NOW()`

However. I would recommend putting an index on both fields.

A combined key wont be of use to you because you it would only speed up searcher for specific date combinations.

Well this is not entirely true because if you use betree a combined key will help you but not as good as if you index them seperately.
Combined keys are very good if you search combinations of fields with equality (=) operator. SIngle field indexes perform better in ragen requests.

You can google a bit for "multidimensional range search".

The reason is that all matching fields in one field can be basically found in log(n) time in btrees.
So your overall runtime will be O(k*log(n)) which is O(log(n)).

Multidimensional Range queries have a runtime of O(sqrt(n)) which is higher. However there are better implementations as well which also acheav logarithmic runtime.
However they are not fully implemented in mysql, so it will be worse or awful depending on the version.

So let me sum up:

- Equality comparisions on single fields: hash index (runtime O(1))
- Range search on single fields: btree index on single fields ( O(log(n)) )
- Equality search on multiple fields: combined hash key (runtime O(1))

those cases are a clear thing...

- Range search on multiple fields: seperate btree indexes ( O(log(n)) )

this is where its not so clear. with current versions its clearly better to index seperately because of the reasons given above.
With a perfect implementation for that use case you could achieve better performance with combined keys but there is no system in know of which supports it.
mysql supports loose indexes (which you need for that) since version 5.0, but only very limited and the query optimizer only utilizes them in rare cases afaik. don't know about newer versions like 5.3 or something.

however with mysql implementing loose indexes combined keys on fields where you do range requests or sorting in different directions become more and more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the use of *inequalities*, and not *equalities*, a composite index isn't going to do any much better (if not worse) than two individual indexes.

I'd advocate for leaning towards two individual indexes on both `began_at` and `finished_at`.

References for Loose index scan:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/09/descending-indexing-and-loose-index-scan/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/loose-index-scan.html

Comment: You've confirmed my experience with that link: there's no way you're going to get MySQL to optimize this query using an index of any type.

Answer (score 1):

The "Index Merge" strategy could come into play from MySQL 5 onwards:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html - which also suggests that separate indexes might be better.

However, I have never been able to get it to work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this sort of question is always: "it depends".  Try it both ways and benchmark and compare execution plans.  Note that the answer also changes as the amount of data in your tables changes and the query workload changes.  Indexes on an evolving system are almost never fire and forget.

Comment: That's a good rule in general, but it's not much of an answer.

Comment: @Ken - it's the correct answer.  Saying "yes, you should create these exact indexes" is a disservice as it's *not that simple*.

Comment: @Donnie. Actually, for many queries, you can figure out what the query optimizer is going to do without having to test. So *usually it is that simple*. Also, people frequently want to ask "I haven't managed to get MySQL to optimize a query of this type, does anybody know how to optimize a query of this type?" in which case saying "it depends" doesn't help. I think that's the case with this question.

Comment: @Ken - I dunno, maybe mysql's query optimizer is dumber than the ones I work with more often where execution plans change depending on table statistics which vary with the data in the table.  Just looking at a query on its own is almost never enough.

Comment: @Donnie, as someone who's told used `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN` to tell MySQL "I know how to optimize this query better than you do" and actually had MySQL listen to me, I can tell you that you need to know a lot more about your query optimizer than simply "try both ways and benchmark."

Comment: @Ken - I agree with that completely, however, I think "try both ways and benchmark" is a better place to start then "trust me, just do it this way".  *shrug*, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, but I'd actually start with indexes on *both* `began_at` and `finished_at`, because one reasonable way you might rewrite this query is like so

```
SELECT *
  FROM runs
 WHERE began_at < NOW()
   AND finished_at > NOW()
```

Which makes it a bit more clear (to me) that each column needs its own index.

Comment: I haven't convinced MySQL to actually use the indices you suggest to optimize this type of query.

Answer (score 0):

I've never gotten MySQL to use use two individual indices for `begin_at` or `finished_at` when trying to optimize this kind of query. Apparently, other people are saying that a composite index won't work either, so it may just not be possible to get MySQL to optimize this query using an index.

Comment: you can create an index for whatever you wabnt. if you index every field seperately you basically have indexed everything. combined indexes are useful if your queries match on combination of fields. they do however perform better with equality comparision and not range comparision than single field indexes.

Comment: @Joe: you totally misunderstood the context of my answer. I've reworded it. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: umm am i understanding correctly that you want mysql to internally optimize the query and use indexes for it? well it will always use indexes for tables if available...

Comment: @Joe: It's not as simple as "it will always use indexes for tables if available". You have to think about the different ways to use an index (#1: lookup a value, #2 lookup a range of values, etc...) and if the way you want the index used makes sense, then MySQL has to actually know how to do it as well. The strategy he wants to use here is called loose index search, and MySQL doesn't know how to do it.

Comment: ok now i think i get you. you are basically right, but he doesnt have his two conditions on the same field. and the issue is eliminated if you ahve seperate and not combined keys.

Comment: however mysql does support loose indexes in late versions so combined keys on fields where you do sorting in different directions or range requests become more and more relevant.

Comment: @Joe: so show me an actual example of MySQL optimizing this type of query using an index. And tell me what version of MySQL you used. I have a query like this that needs some optimization help.