# mysql is not using index on BETWEEN query

Tags: mysql, sql

Table has 100,845 rows. I'm trying to detect country by IP (ip2long) in the range of IPs for the specific country.

```
SELECT `country_code` FROM `geo_ip_country`
WHERE 3271557119 BETWEEN `start_ip_long` AND `end_ip_long`
```

both `start_ip_long` and `end_ip_long` are indexed. However according to `explain query`, the query is not using index and performs full table scan, all 100,845 rows.

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  geo_ip_country  ALL     key_name        100845  Using where
```

I've tried:

- making separate index on `start_ip_long` AND `end_ip_long`
- making composite index on (start_ip_long, end_ip_long)
- making only one index on `start_ip_long`

How can I optimize this query or table so that it used indexes in this case?

Comment: Should there not be an index on `end_ip_long`?

Comment: It is not necessary for my application. But I though it is needed to optimize a query I have a composite index on (start_ip_long, end_ip_long). I just tried to index only `start_ip_long` and it did not change the way the query behaves.

Comment: It's not indexed because in order for the query to compare to `end_ip_long`, the whole table must be read and scanned.  You'll likely need an index on `(start_ip_long,end_ip_long)`.

Comment: What do you mean by `(geo_ip_country, start_ip_long)`, exactly? Isn't `geo_ip_country` a table, not a column?

Comment: I would first of all try two separate new indexes, one on `start_ip_long`, and one on `end_ip_long`. (See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347904/mysql-composite-indexes-and-operator-between) for some rationale on that suggestion.)

Comment: @Bacon, I've tried with composite index on (start_ip_long,end_ip_long) it did not change the data in explain, but it did make query faster

Comment: @Matt, thank you. I've studied that question. In my case composite index is recommended, but it still does full table scan, according to explain. So I'm still puzzled as to how I can optimize it.

Comment: Looking through @MattGibson's link, it looks like Ken Bloom and other say that MySQL just won't use indexes on this type of query.  As it stands you could try to use [index hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html), but it's possible that MySQL will just ignore that.

Comment: Thank you, very good information!

Comment: I'm not sure that MySQL will *never* use indexes on this type of query. It's hard to outguess a query optimiser, and it might just be that people haven't had much luck in their particular circumstances—a query optimiser that knows about the distribution of the data in its tables will sometimes decide to ignore what looks like a sensible index for a table scan that it thinks will be faster. I'd still *try* two separate indexes in this particular case, personally.

Comment: (Though it depends somewhat on what performance problems are actually being encountered... Table scanning 100,845 rows with a couple of integer comparisons shouldn't actually take that long, should it? How fast is this query running at the moment, @dmit?)

Comment: @Matt at the moment in staging environment it is at 0.0312 seconds, but there are no other concurrent queries being performed.

Comment: Frankly, then, I really wouldn't bother optimising at this stage. How many concurrent queries are you going to need before that grows to any significant number? By the time you've got that many queries, you'll need bigger hardware just to cope with the number of connections you'll be dealing with, surely? Plus, if a small table like that is being hit a lot, it'll probably stay in memory... "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil".

Comment: @Matt, thank you for the information. I will surely leave it like that.

Comment: Have a look at this

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125474/mysql-optimal-index-for-between-queries][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125474/mysql-optimal-index-for-between-queries